# Npgsql using .NET on Ubuntu: how to write database query result to console?

Tags: .net, postgresql, ubuntu

I am using .NET `Npgsql` library on Ubuntu for connecting to PostgreSQL dbms.

In my database I have a declared FUNCTION "user_plan()", which returns a SETOF `SELECT` query results:

```
CREATE FUNCTION user_plan(varchar(20), int) RETURNS SETOF user_plan_type AS
$$
    SELECT pr.participant, t.talk_id, t.start_time, t.description, t.room
    FROM talks t JOIN participant_registrations pr USING(event)
    WHERE pr.participant=$1
    ORDER BY 3
    LIMIT $2;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

When I test it directly from psql environment, everything woks as expected. But when I call the FUNCTION using `Npgsql` library either this way:

```
using (var query = new NpgsqlCommand())
{
    query.Connection = conn;
    query.CommandText = "SELECT user_plan(@user, @limit::int)";
    query.Parameters.AddWithValue("user", login);
    query.Parameters.AddWithValue("limit", limit);
    using (var dr = query.ExecuteReader()) {
        while(dr.Read()){
            Console.Write("{0} \n", dr[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Or this way:

```
using (var query = new NpgsqlCommand())
{
    query.Connection = conn;
    query.CommandText = "SELECT user_plan(@user, @limit::int)";
    query.Parameters.AddWithValue("user", login);
    query.Parameters.AddWithValue("limit", limit);
    using (var dr = query.ExecuteReader()) {
        while(dr.Read()){
            Console.WriteLine(dr.GetString(0));
        }
    }
}
```

I have got the following error:

```
System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal: 
The field 'user_plan' has a type currently unknown to Npgsql (OID 16642).
You can retrieve it as a string by marking it as unknown, please see the FAQ.
```

I just wanted to write to console the set of results for the `user_plan()` query. How can I do it?

Comment: The error is about the *query*. You return a user-defined type from the query, yet you try to read it as a string (it isn't). This has nothing to do with the Console or Ubuntu

Comment: Ok, I have figured it out. It should have been like this:
`query.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM user_plan(@user, @limit::int)";`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `query` itself. It returns the function type, not the return value.

Instead of:

```
query.CommandText = "SELECT user_plan(@user, @limit::int)";
```

Should have been:

```
query.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM user_plan(@user, @limit::int)";
```